# Measure execution time of command I just executed without interrupting it now

Tags: bash, time

Usually I measure execution times with

```
time updater
```

Unfortunately I already started the updater and do not want to interrupt it because this would cause other trouble.

How can I still see tomorrow when I return to work the time it needed to complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new terminal and execute `date` to get the current time. Type `date` and hit Enter in the terminal running `updater`. That will show you the time that `updater` finishes. Subtract the two.

Answer (score 2):

appcheck.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGRAM1=updater
PPCHK=1

while [ "$PPCHK" -eq "1" ]
do
    PPCHK=$(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -c $PROGRAM1)
    sleep 1;
done
```

And then `time appcheck.sh`